# Check if internet connected only than make jbutton clickable otherwise jbutton is not clickable or disabled

Tags: java

I am making a gui in which i want to make a feature accessible only if device is offline so how could i make a ***jbutton that is only enabled when offline***.

I want the jbutton to be displayed but not clickable.

Comment: can you also post the question of which this is duplicate?

Comment: @Pshemo can you paste link of question of which this is duplicate?

Comment: It should be visible at top of your post. You may need to refresh this page to see it.

Comment: thanks got it sorry for all that i am new here

Comment: You are welcome, and no problem.